# How do I distinguish text conversations from the same contact with different phone numbers?

Tags: iphone, contacts, text

I have a contact with whom I share text messages from two different phone numbers. How can I distinguish the two text conversations? Right now, it labels them identically with Full Name at the top, and first name beneath.

iPhone 6 running ios 10.

Comment: There is no way other than assigning the phone numbers to two contacts with similar (though not the same) names or with different profile pictures.

Comment: Urgh, I thought this might be the case

Comment: Can you create 2 separate but similar contacts for this person with 1 of the numbers assigned to each one?  Maybe similar names with a "-1" or "-cell" after their name.

Comment: I guess you could but that's pretty hacky. They are the same person, and the Contacts app allows you to assign them different phone numbers, and you want all of the other information associated with the contact in the one place

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is: you can't distinguish the different numbers from a single contact